# How to add parameters to an existing style

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following button in my XAML:

```
<Button Content="ADD"
        Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" />
```

I would like to keep the style and create a validation rule for it, like if some textbox is empty it should disable the button and set a tooltip on it.

So I tried this:

```
<Button Content="ADD"
        Command="{Binding AddDateCommand}"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Margin="8 0 0 0">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
             <triggers to check the rules and set the attributes/>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Can only base on a Style with target type that is base type
>   'IFrameworkInputElement'

Comment: Seems like your style is missing the attribute TargetType="{x:Type Button}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will get an **error : Style can be set only once** in your present code.
2. You have to use TargetType with BasedOn styles.

So, define your style should be conceptually like this :

```
<Style x:Key="MaterialDesignFlatButton" TargetType="Button">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="NewStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" 
       TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
         <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=tb, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" Value="10"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
         </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Cornsilk"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="15"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="MediumPurple"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `IsEnabled` property of the button if you have one `TextBox`:

```
<Button Content="ADD"
    Command="{Binding AddDateCommand}"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Margin="8 0 0 0"
    IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=yourTxtBox, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

But for two `TextBoxes` you should use:

```
<Button.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
          <Style.Triggers>
              <MultiDataTrigger>
                     <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=firstTxtBox, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" Value="0"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=lastTxtBox, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" Value="0"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
             </MultiDataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
</Button.Style>
```